# Let a user draw any number using turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a script in python that is supposed to let the user enter any number and it will be drawn on the screen. Right now, the code I have won't draw the numbers and is only print 0.99999... I'm not getting error messages, so I'm unsure of what I should be editing to get this thing working. Help would be appreciated.

```
number = int(input("Pick a number"))
print (number) #Number is definitley a number

moveto(-500,0)
for i in range(1,len(str(number))+1):
    digit = ((number % (10 ** i) - (number % 10 ** i - 1)) / 10 ** i - 1)
    print(digit)
    drawnum(digit)
```

And here's the library I'm importing from.

```
from turtle import *

def moveto(x,y):
    pu()
    goto(x,y)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

#x and y let the user place their numbers down, d is length of sides.
def nine(d):
    point = pos()
    fd(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d*2)
    bk(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def eight(d):
    point = pos()
    fd(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d*2)
    for i in range(3):
        rt(90)
        fd(d)
    bk(d)
    lt(90)
    fd(d)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def seven(d):
    point = pos()
    fd(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d*2)
    bk(d*2)
    lt(90)
    bk(d)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def six(d):
    point = pos()
    fd(d)
    bk(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d*2)
    for i in range(3):
        lt(90)
        fd(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def five(d):
    point = pos()
    fd(d)
    bk(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d)
    lt(90)
    fd(d)
    for i in range(2):
        rt(90)
        fd(d)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def four(d):
    point = pos()
    rt(90)
    fd(d)
    for i in range(2):
        lt(90)
        fd(d)
    bk(d * 2)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def three(d):
    point = pos()
    for i in range(2):
        fd(d)
        rt(90)
    fd(d)
    for i in range(2):
        bk(d)
        rt(90)
    bk(d)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def two(d):
    point = pos()
    fd(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d)
    lt(90)
    for i in range(2):
        bk(d)
        lt(90)
    bk(d)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def one(d):
    point = pos()
    pu()
    fd(d)
    pd()
    rt(90)
    fd(d*2)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def zero(d):
    point = pos()
    fd(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d*2)
    rt(90)
    fd(d)
    rt(90)
    fd(d*2)
    pu()
    goto(point)
    pd()
    setheading(0)

def drawnum(n):
    d=100
    if (n == 1):
        one(d)
    if (n ==2):
        two(d)
    if (n==3):
        three(d)
    if (n==4):
       four(d)
    if (n==5):
        five(d)
    if (n==6):
        six(d)
    if (n==7):
        seven(d)
    if (n==8):
        eight(d)
    if (n==9):
        nine(d)
    if (n==0):
        zero(d)
    pu()
    fd(1.5*d)
    pd()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running into floating point accuracy issues. Instead of doing math on the number, you should better use the string representation of it.

```
for digit in str(number):
 ...
```